# Run script before building image in dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, scripting, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that needs to run a bash script before building.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG  IMAGE_VERSION
FROM path_to_image/images/base:${IMAGE_VERSION}
CMD  /code/run-app
```

The script will find the latest image version by scraping a website. I can't use the "latest" key word as the images are not hosted on docker hub. I need the IMAGE_VERSION to be equal to the output of a script before running the docker build command?

Comment: soo run the command, store it in IMAGE_VERSION, then run docker build?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant run the script manually like that. The docker image is being built by an external script I don't have access to. I need the script to run when the "docker build ." command is ran by the external script.

Comment: `The docker image is being built by an external script I don't have access to` Then it is not possible. Change that "external script" or change your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script outputs the tag you need, you can do something like this (assuming your script is called myscript.sh)

```
docker build --build-arg IMAGE_VERSION=$(./myscript.sh) -t myimage .
```

Comment: I have looked at this as a potential solution before but unfortunately I would have to edit many scripts from many different micro-services. Some of which I don't have access to.